# iOS Check if an image is present in the library

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am currently working on a project that has a requirement that the captured photos should be saved in Photo Library. I accomplish that using following code :

```
self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[self.library saveImage:imgResult toAlbum:bundleIDForAlbum withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
```

However I don't want to save it to library if the image already exist in it.

Like -

```
if( ! [self checkIfImageExists])
{
    self.library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [self.library saveImage:imgResult toAlbum:bundleIDForAlbum withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error!=nil) {
                NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
            }
        }];
}
```

Writing a method definition -

```
-(BOOL) checkIfImageExists
{
    //What do I do here???
}
```

**Please see :** I am looking for an intelligent solution rather than maintaining a record myself by writing it to local files with name, and keeping another record of checking which file name has already been saved to Library.

**EDIT**

Images are populated on by one from UIImagePickerController, and then saved on click of Done Button.

If User reviews and adds one more image, there are 4 already saved images. And one is new. I want only the new one to be saved to the library now.

Comment: Where are these images coming from, how could it be a duplicate? And who says your proposed solution isn't intelligent?

Comment: Check the edit, I just wish to know if there is any way to check if image is already present in the library. I agree my solution is not dumb, but I am positive that there should be a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1):

I assume, this is not possible.

The one thing you can try out is, make use of SHA-1, which rendered as a hexadecimal number, 40 digits long for a file. Alternately, you can use MD5.

Create a SHA-1 representation of your `imgResult`, then enumerate all the photo library images and create the SHA-1 representation for each to compare.

I don't have full hope, because the location, time and other metadata, which will save along with the Photo-library images will change the binary file content and the SHA-1 result in a same image.